# Exclude path on FileZilla files search

Tags: windows-7, ftp, sftp, filezilla, file-filter

I’d like to exclude directories from the file search window but I can’t manage to do that.
As you can see the argument **Path** → **Not Contains** don’t prevent fileZilla to search into the LOGS folder…

[image: FileZilla search window]

*FileZilla version 3.25.1 (just updated) on Windows 7 (64 bits)*

Answer (score 0):

FileZilla check files in LOGS for compilance with first 3 conditions. Make condition with "path not contain" first

Comment: From my tests, this still searches those directories but doesn't include results from those directories.